# Как сделать, чтоб пользователь продолжил работу с программой с того самого места, где закончил?

Tags: android

В моей программе имеются несколько activity. Пользователь ею пользуется, радуется. Ложится спать, отключает телефон, а при включении пользователь опять на первой активити.

Как сделать, чтобы он оказался на той активити, где вчера закончил?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю можно так

1. Создаете класс, для работы с `SharedPreferences`, в нем два метода, записать индекс или имя активити и считать это имя или индекс.
2. При каждой смене активити вызываете метод записи у класса из первого пункта и передаете в качестве параметра имя или индекс активити на которую перешел,  или вернулся пользователь.
3. Сделать стартовую активити, которая будет при старте приложения вызывать метод считывания у класса из первого пункта и, в зависимости от полученного результата, открывать нужную активити.

Comment: Спасибо! Ночью и я додумался до такого. Все работает!))